# Converting a Python regular expression to C#

Tags: c#, python, regex

I have this regular expression in python:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="(?P<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)">'
```

I want an equivalent regular expression string for C#. This string gives a parsing error in c#. Thanks in advance.

I've tried this:

```
Regex rc = new Regex("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"GALX\" value=\"(?P<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\">");
```

It gives me this error:

```
parsing \"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"GALX\" value=\"(?P<galx>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\">\" - Unrecognized grouping construct.
```

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the "P" so that the "<" is right after the "?" it parses fine.

[Note .NET grouping syntax.](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Comment: yes, compiled fine...but I wonder if it's the same expression as in the above python string?

Comment: [Going with "yes" (click through).](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: @UzairFarooq - Just beware that working with regex groups in C# are significantly different than those used in Python.